# Why would someone practice free lensing?

Tags: effect

I heard the other day someone talking about free lensing, something to do with removing the lens from the body.

What would be the point in this exercise and what is the achieved effect?

Comment: The accepted answer to the suggested duplicate addresses everything in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, by moving the lens vertical axis relative to the body vertical axis, you are moving the plane at which things are in focus. This way you can, say, shoot a model full body and yet have the face in focus while the rest is not. Also, small amounts of light creeping in the openings will create a kind of "ethereal" effect on the photos. You can see great examples and a guide to freelensing here: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/insights/blogs/photography/how-freelensing.html . Another application could be "Miniature faking" (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_faking) - basically defocusing a normal photo in a way such that it seems to be a macro photo of some miniature instead of reality.

To do this (the non-parallel plane of focus) in a more traditional way, usually tilt-shift lenses are used; they are very expensive lenses, made to be as free as possible from deformations of the resulting image and used specially in architecture photography. Other solutions are lenses like the Lens Baby system which enable this kind of effects.

Comment: The more traditional way to do non-parallel plane of focus is with a view camera. Tilt-shift lenses were created to mimic the movements possible with a view camera.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I used "traditional" in a wrong way, I meant "conventional" or something like that